# Get User by UserKey not UserName in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I can get a user by using their username like so:

```
Dim user = Membership.GetUser("myUserName")
```

How can I get a user using their UserKey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Membership.GetUser` method has an overload which takes a user key (as object).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152019.aspx

As long as the key that you pass in is not a string or boolean, it should use that overload.